# Can't modify or delete SELinux user

Tags: rhel, selinux

I was playing around with `user_u` in the targeted policy on RHEL 6.5.  I'm logged in as root in the unconfined context, so I have full ability to change anything I want.  I've also switched to permissive mode just in case.  I originally had user_u set up to have the MLS/MCS settings "s0:c0.c50".  This state was functioning properly with no issues(that I'm aware of).  To test changing this with commands, I typed in this:

```
semanage user -m -r s0:c0.c51 user_u
```

This ran without any problems, and I was able to verify that it worked correctly with `semanage user -l`. `user_u` now has the MLS/MCS of "s0:c0.c51".  However, if I try to modify user_u or either of the users tied to user_u(named `bob` and `alice`), I get an error that looks like this:

> libsemanage.validate_handler: MLS range s0:c0.c50 for Unix user bob exceeds allowed range s0:c0.c51 for SELinux user user_u(No such file or directory).
>   libsemanage.validate_handler: seuser mapping  [bob -> (user_u, s0:c0-c50)] is invalid (No such file or directory).
>   libsemanage.dbase_llist_iterate: could not iterate over records(No such file or directory).

The confusing part is that s0:c0.c50 'exceeds' s0:c0.c51.  If I try to modify user_u, it complains about bob.  If I try to delete bob, it complains about alice.  If I try to delete alice, it complains about bob.  I effectively can't change any of them(through the GUI tools or the command line).

Initially I tried backing out the changes from semanage and going back to `user_u` with s0:c0.c50, but that didn't work, so I tried s0-s0:c0.c1023, which also didn't work.  I noticed the errors never mentioned s0-s0:c0.c1023 so it's like they're failing before really changing user_u's MCS/MLS.

I could only find a few examples that were similar online, and the only one that I found with advice said to delete the user mappings from /etc/selinux/targeted/seusers and to run `semodule -B`.  I tried that, and `semodule -B` fails with the same error messages.  I have also replaced the deleted portions of seusers and tried `semodule -B` to no avail.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?  This was a sandbox environment so it's easy to just go back to the original image, but I won't have that luxury in a deployed environment.

Answer (score 0):

A version of this happened to me, similar enough for internet searches anyway.  I was not altering the MLS context, but I got odd errors like where that was invalidate like in the original question here:

```
libsemanage.validate_handler: MLS range s0-s0:c0.c1023 for Unix user elflord exceeds allowed range s0 for SELinux user sysadm_u (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.validate_handler: seuser mapping [elflord -> (sysadm_u, s0-s0:c0.c1023)] is invalid (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.dbase_llist_iterate: could not iterate over records (No such file or directory).
```

This was from running `semodule [-i|-B`, and particularly confusing with `-i` when the module made no mention of `sysadm_u`.

The cause was previously (and unrelated-ly) trying to *add* a role to `sysadmn_u` like this:

```
semanage user -m -R webadm_r sysadm_u
```

The man page is ambiguous about the functionality of `-R` with `-m`, but evidently it does not modify in the sense of *adding* a role, it replaces them:

```
> seinfo -u sysadm_u -x

Users: 1
   user sysadm_u roles webadm_r level s0 range s0;
```

Whoops, `sysadm_r` is gone.  This also meant `elflord` could not log in, at least via ssh: `Unable to get valid context for elflord` is sent over the wire.

What's more, although I did not stipulate `-r`, that got set to a minimal `level s0 range 0`, which is what the text of the error seems most concerned about.

The fix was to redo the user modification including the original role(s) and range:

```
semanage user -m -R { sysadm_r webadm_r } sysadm_u -r s0-s0:c0.c1023
```